# Find the Exception from Rakefile in rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

Used ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.1. I had a requirement to keep track of all the rake tasks in the Project, whether the rake tasks are success or not. For that I used the Rakefile , it will create an entry when a rake task starts and at the end it will update the end time of that particular rake task. This is done by the following below code, in rakefile

```
 start_time = Time.current
 require 'tasks/delayed_tasks'
 rake_info = Rake.application.top_level_tasks.join
 Rake::Task["create_audit_entry"].invoke("#{rake_info}","#{start_time}")
 at_exit { Rake::Task["update_audit_entry"].invoke("#{rake_info}","#{start_time}") if $!.nil?
```

But the issue happens when there is an exception throws at any of the rake tasks, need to  update the log_table as the error encountered. Since too much rake tasks are present, updating the rake files is a big issue, is there any way to find the exception occurs in any of the rake tasks from the rakefile rather than updating all the rake tasks.

Comment: It’s still ruby file: just surround call to `invoke` with `try`/`rescue`.

Comment: @mudasobwa but the error is captured by the rake file only, that Exception is not accessible inside the rakefile.

Comment: @mudasobwa updated the comment: but the error is captured by the rake task only, that Exception is not accessible inside the rakefile